# notification if no reply to a mail in Gmail (Java)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I would like to know if it is possible to know if a recipient has answered a definit email .

What is te best way to do this in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

There are `Message-ID`, `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers in the e-mail message (see http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html or http://wesmorgan.blogspot.ch/2012/07/understanding-email-headers-part-ii.html). You have to keep the `Message-ID` of an e-mail message you are interested in, and then parse the headers of the incoming messages, if they contain your ID.

As for the way to do it in Java, read the [Java Mail API Tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-mail-api-tutorial) and study the [javax.mail JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/mail/package-summary.html) (and sub-packages).

**Warning:** Athough commonly used by most e-mail clients, these headers are not mandatory, so there is no 100% secure way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure we understand the problem, you want to know how to tell if a recipient has sent a reply to you for a message you sent to the recipient, right?

As Jozef describes, the In-Reply-To and References headers are the standard way of doing this, but some mailers don't properly include them in replies.  Another approach is to include a unique ID in the Subject of the original message.  Replies almost always include the original Subject without change, prepended by "Re:" or equivalent.